# Unable to locate web-elements on homepage of a website

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, webdriver

For software testing am working on https://www.freecrm.com/ website. I'm unable to locate any web-elements on homepage of that website

I am asking questions on this app for the first time.so hope I hope I can explain my problem properly because I really need help with this.

I am working on this website https://www.freecrm.com/ . I have confirmed that I have all the correct XPath for web-element on the homepage of that website

but it is showing an error that says:

> rg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element.

If you need I can give you my id and password for the website but please help me.

I am watching below video tutorial and working on that website.
[image].

I am adding a google drive link where there is my whole project if you want to look. please help I really need to finish this project. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ztQYWtdx87xbQ0hvgZDAT1TGkaxacul-?usp=drive_link

Comment: Dummy credentials for testing?